# Open file from Azure Blob Storage and append them in a new file

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I can't seems to wrap up this problem.

I have several files in Azure container called `container1`. For example :

```
s1_cat.json
s2_cat.json
s3_dog.json
s1_dog.json
s2_dog.json
```

Example of content of each json looks like this, say `s1_cat.json` :

```
{"abc" : "def", "ghi" : 0}
{"123" : "456", "789" : 1}
```

and `s2_cat.json`:

```
{"klm" : "nop", "qrs" : 2}
{"2203" : "1994", "000" : 3}
```

Hardly a correct format of json to deal with.
Anyway, I want to append them based on keyword `cat` or `dog` to a new file to a different container called `temp` like so (as `cat.json`):

```
{"abc" : "def", "ghi" : 0}
{"123" : "456", "789" : 1}
{"klm" : "nop", "qrs" : 2}
{"2203" : "1994", "000" : 3}
```

My current code :

```
try:

    container_name = 'container1'
    filepath = 'temp'
    account_name = 'xxx'
    account_key = 'xxx'

    blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
    appendblobservice = AppendBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)

    data = blobService.list_blobs(container_name, prefix='temp')

       
    for blob in data:

        if 'cat' in blob.name :

            filename = "cat.json"

            blobService.get_blob_to_path(container_name, blob_name=blob.name, file_path=filepath)

            #I stuck from here.....
            #read the json file
            cat = blobService.get_blob_to_text(container_name, blob.name)
            cat = cat.content.split('\n')
            cat = list(filter(None, cat )) #remove empty element in the list
            #display result
            print(cat)
            #stuck here....                



    
except Exception as ex:
    print('Unable to connect!')
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)
```

My problem is I dont know how I can append the first `cat` with the second `cat` file. I only manage to display them. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you just define a string before the loop, then in each loop, add the content to the string?

Comment: what do you mean by string? Can you show if you dont mind. @IvanYang

Comment: check it below, please correct me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Hi @IvanYang. Sorry for late response. It doesn't work for me. Instead I created a new list and append to it. However, I'm looking at different approach now. Thank you for follow up!

Comment: Please share with us if you find a good solution. And also you can elaborate your issue, then I can keep following up it:).

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a string, then add each content to the string in each loop. Code like below:

```
#other code

mystring=""

for blob in data:

        if 'cat' in blob.name :

            filename = "cat.json"

            blobService.get_blob_to_path(container_name, blob_name=blob.name, file_path=filepath)

            #I stuck from here.....
            #read the json file
            cat = blobService.get_blob_to_text(container_name, blob.name)
            cat = cat.content.split('\n')
            cat = list(filter(None, cat )) #remove empty element in the list
            #display result
            print(cat)

            #here, append each content to the string
            mystring += cat + "\n"

            #stuck here....
```